# Add swipe for the page along with tab swipe in android

Tags: android, tabs

I'm trying to use tabView. When I swipe the page the page is not swiping along with tabs.Can't figure out the problem.Kindly help me.

My Activity code:

```
public class Notify extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
    String contentText="I'm using android notification text." + "It's working fine, but the problem is that we have to create a big textview";
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    private String[] frag={"Books","Canvas","Fragments","Needed"};
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ActionBar a;
    DemoCollectionPagerAdapter mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notification);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        a = getSupportActionBar();
        a.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        //  tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Books"));
        //tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Canvas"));
        //tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Fragments"));
        //tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Needed"));


        for (String tab_name : frag) {
            a.addTab(a.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.CYAN);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter);
        mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter = new DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Log.i("TAG", "message");
        //  getSupportActionBar().hide();

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                a.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }


    public void onClick(View view){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(Notify.this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Notify me");
        builder.setContentText(contentText);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.images);
        builder.setTicker("Hey! You got it");
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        Intent i=new Intent(Notify.this,Newactivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(Newactivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(i);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //Settings
        Intent j=new Intent(Notify.this,Setting.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder_settings=TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder_settings.addParentStack(Setting.class);
        stackBuilder_settings.addNextIntent(j);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent_settings=stackBuilder_settings.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //help
        Intent k=new Intent(Notify.this,Help.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder_help=TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder_help.addParentStack(Help.class);
        stackBuilder_help.addNextIntent(k);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent_help=stackBuilder_help.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        builder.addAction(R.drawable.images,"Settings",pendingIntent_settings);
        builder.addAction(R.drawable.images,"Help",pendingIntent_help);


        Notification notification= builder.build();
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(1234, notification);
    }

    public void bigText(View view) {
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle style= new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        style.setBigContentTitle("Big Notification");
        style.bigText(contentText);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentText(contentText);
        builder.setContentTitle("Big Notification");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.images);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setStyle(style);

        Notification notification= builder.build();
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(567, notification);

    }

    public void bigpicture(View view) {
        Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.one);
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle style=new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        style.setBigContentTitle("Big Picture");
        style.setBigContentTitle(contentText);style.bigPicture(bmp);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentText(contentText);
        builder.setContentTitle("Big Notification");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.images);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setStyle(style);

        Notification notification= builder.build();
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(111, notification);

    }

    public void inboxStyle(View view) {
        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle style =new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        style.setBigContentTitle("Inbox style");
        style.addLine("Line one");
        style.addLine("Line two");
        style.addLine("Line three");

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentText(contentText);
        builder.setContentTitle("Big Notification");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.images);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setStyle(style);

        Notification notification= builder.build();
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(279, notification);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());


    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

My Adapter code:

```
public class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                BooksFragment myFragment = new BooksFragment();
                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                data.putInt("current_page", position+1);
                myFragment.setArguments(data);
                return myFragment;
            case 1:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 2:
                return new Fragment2();
            case 3:
                return new Fragment2();

        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    private class BooksFragment extends Fragment {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View root= inflater.inflate(R.layout.splashscreen,container, false);
            ImageView imageView= (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            return root;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ check this

Comment: I tried from that also but unable to figure out the issue :(

Comment: can you post your xml?

Comment: set  app:tabMode="scrollable" in TabLayout in xml. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

I got this from here. New material design http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/  hope it helps you

Comment: thanks bro it solved my swipe issue. I have to add data inside fragments. :)